# The type org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart is not accessible after adding JFreeChart and JCommon libraries

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am new to Java, and trying to get to grips with JFreeChart. I am trying to run some demo code from this website: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jfreechart/jfreechart_xy_chart.htm

Here is the demo code (the rest of the question is below):

```
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.BasicStroke; 

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel; 
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart; 
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset; 
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries; 
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame; 
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities; 
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot; 
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory; 
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation; 
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection; 
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;

public class XYLineChart_AWT extends ApplicationFrame {

   public XYLineChart_AWT( String applicationTitle, String chartTitle ) {
      super(applicationTitle);
      JFreeChart xylineChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
         chartTitle ,
         "Category" ,
         "Score" ,
         createDataset() ,
         PlotOrientation.VERTICAL ,
         true , true , false);

      ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel( xylineChart );
      chartPanel.setPreferredSize( new java.awt.Dimension( 560 , 367 ) );
      final XYPlot plot = xylineChart.getXYPlot( );

      XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer( );
      renderer.setSeriesPaint( 0 , Color.RED );
      renderer.setSeriesPaint( 1 , Color.GREEN );
      renderer.setSeriesPaint( 2 , Color.YELLOW );
      renderer.setSeriesStroke( 0 , new BasicStroke( 4.0f ) );
      renderer.setSeriesStroke( 1 , new BasicStroke( 3.0f ) );
      renderer.setSeriesStroke( 2 , new BasicStroke( 2.0f ) );
      plot.setRenderer( renderer ); 
      setContentPane( chartPanel ); 
   }

   private XYDataset createDataset( ) {
      final XYSeries firefox = new XYSeries( "Firefox" );          
      firefox.add( 1.0 , 1.0 );          
      firefox.add( 2.0 , 4.0 );          
      firefox.add( 3.0 , 3.0 );          

      final XYSeries chrome = new XYSeries( "Chrome" );          
      chrome.add( 1.0 , 4.0 );          
      chrome.add( 2.0 , 5.0 );          
      chrome.add( 3.0 , 6.0 );          

      final XYSeries iexplorer = new XYSeries( "InternetExplorer" );          
      iexplorer.add( 3.0 , 4.0 );          
      iexplorer.add( 4.0 , 5.0 );          
      iexplorer.add( 5.0 , 4.0 );          

      final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection( );          
      dataset.addSeries( firefox );          
      dataset.addSeries( chrome );          
      dataset.addSeries( iexplorer );
      return dataset;
   }

   public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
      XYLineChart_AWT chart = new XYLineChart_AWT("Browser Usage Statistics",
         "Which Browser are you using?");
      chart.pack( );          
      RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( chart );          
      chart.setVisible( true ); 
   }
}
```

I am unable to run the demo code because I am unable import any class from the JFreeChart library.

An example may be that when I try to import `org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel`, I get the error "The type org.jfreechart.ChartPanel is not accessible"

I have followed the PDF installation guide (http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download/jfreechart-1.0.0-install.pdf)

I have imported the libraries to the project folder.

I checked the library JARs and they contain all of the classes I am trying to import.

System Information:

JRE Version - JavaSE 11/ JDK 11

Eclipse Version - 4.11.0

The libraries should be imported and the code should run fine, though Eclipse says they are inaccessible.

Thanks in advance for anyone that took the time to read this :)

Comment: Use Maven or Gradle for dependencies, don't try to do it manually :) See https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html / https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html for starting in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Given you're using Java 11, you have probably also created a

```
module-info.java
```

file. It would be something on the line of

```
module yourmodulename { 
   ...
}
```

---

To gain access to the `jfreechart` automatic module, you need to *require* it

```
module yourmodulename { 
   requires jfreechart;
}
```

[image]

---

Also, the PDF tutorial you're following is pretty dated. Use Maven or Gradle as dependency management tools.
Let me know in case you need further clarifications on that.

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
implementation('org.jfree:jfreechart:1.5.0')
```

Comment: The example shown works with [_jfreechart-1.0.19/jcommon-1.0.23_](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart/1.0.19), but the poster will have to [_migrate_](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart#migration-from-jfreechart-10x).